# Boundness by a specific differential operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Denote $\mathbb{T}$ the 1-torus and let  $G : H^1(\mathbb{T}) \to H^1(\mathbb{T})$  be Frechet differentiable such that $G(0) = 0$ and
$DG$ maps bounded sets in $H^1$ into bounded sets in $\mathcal{L}(H^1).$
Consider the sequence of operators $\{L_n\}$ defined by 
$$L_n = \sqrt{n^2-n\Delta}.$$ 
Assume that there exists a bounded sequence $\{u_n\}$ in $H^1(\mathbb{T})$ 
such that the sequence $\{L_n u_n\}$ is bounded in $L^2.$

Is the sequence $\{L_n G(u_n)\}$ bounded in $L^2$ ?